# Authentication/Authorization in Gmail API

Tags: authentication, gmail-api

I am creating an app to extract user's emails once they arrive at the uesr' Gmail account (automatically).

After reading Gmail API, I conclude that each extraction (of a Gmail) would require a user authorization through the Oauth 2.0 flow.

I am wondering if there is a way to extract an (G)email by providing an api_key (each gmail account would have its own api_key, obtained by gmail account user registering the app with Google)? The key is to extract (g)email without requiring manual authorizations by gmail account owners.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/55598120/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the issue carefully, I have drawn a conclusion that Gmail (Hotmail, Yahoo mail are the same) does not support api_key authentication method for email accesses,
i.e. each time before an app accesses a gmail count, manual authentication is needed.

Comment: Can someone from gmail or an expert on this confirm if the finding/answer above is correct; if not please provide correct answer. I also want to sign-in my server program without manual browser authentication. So the authentication must all be automated; I don't want user interaction at all.